# Composition of functions in inequalities

Tags: inequality, function-and-relation-composition

i'm doing a demonstration, and i am stuck in this part.
If i have an inequality such as:

$f(x)\leq g(x)$

Can i compose both sides? Like this, for example:

$h(f(x))\leq h(g(x))$

What would happen if $h(x)$ is monotonically decreasing? I think it would change the inequality, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes it will modify the inequality.

Comment: Consider $f(x)=1$ and $g(x)=2$. Now choose some $h$ with $h(1) = 1$ and $h(2)=-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, I would say that this doesn't really have to do with composition of functions at all. Suppose that $v$ and $w$ are real numbers with $v\le w$.

- If $h$ is increasing, then we can conclude that $h(v) \le h(w)$.
- If $h$ is decreasing, then we can conclude that $h(v) \ge h(w)$.
- If neither, then we can't immediately draw any conclusion.

All of this holds with $v=f(x)$ and $w=g(x)$ just the same,  but it doesn't really have to do with the fact that $v$ and $w$ are values of two functions at the same point.

Answer (score 0):

This is true of $h$ is increasing. If $h$ is decreasing, the inequality would flip. If $h$ is not monotonic, you cannot compare the compositions.